# MongoDB query with $elemMatch

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to retrieve values from a MongoDB collection using tornado and python.

The value which I am giving for search is in a list, I want the entire collection to be listed but the values other than the given values must not be shown in the list variable.

My data in table:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564b313b3f32df05fc905570"),
    "RequiredDate" : "17-11-2015",
    "RequestedDate" : "17-11-2015",
    "Pid" : [
            "564b22373f32df05fc905564",
            "5630baac3f32df134c18b682"
    ],
    "email" : "abishek@gmail.com",
    "UName" : "abishek",
    "Uid" : "564b21003f32df05fc905563",
    "phone" : "9988776655",
    "PName" : [
            "balu",
            "prakash"
    ],
    "Registration" : [
            "TN 45 AG 5688",
            "TN 45 AS 5655"
    ],
    "Rid" : "564b313b3f32df05fc905570"
}
```

My query:

```
db.collection.find({"Rid" : "564b313b3f32df05fc905570"},{"Pid": {$elemMatch:{"Pid":"5630baac3f32df134c18b682","Registration": "TN 45 AS 5655"}}},{"_id": false}).pretty()
```

The desired output is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("564b313b3f32df05fc905570"),
    "RequiredDate" : "17-11-2015",
    "RequestedDate" : "17-11-2015",
    "Pid" : "5630baac3f32df134c18b682",
    "email" : "abishek@gmail.com",
    "UName" : "abishek",
    "Uid" : "564b21003f32df05fc905563",
    "phone" : "9988776655",
    "PName" : [
            "balu",
            "prakash"
    ],
    "Registration" : "TN 45 AS 5655",
    "Rid" : "564b313b3f32df05fc905570"
}
```

Is `$elemMatch` the correct way to get the output, or is there any other way to achieve the desired output.

---

**Explanation:**

In the suggested answer there a JSON object inside of the list and here I have a particular value where only the Pid is am aware of the Registration value is received from another table is matched with the value of Registration in this particular record and then displayed as a single record without showing other Pid and Registration.
And I am getting only the `_id` in output, and not the entire modified record.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Comment: @AnirudhModi There is a version of [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) that is used for projection and not as a query operator. But the general case with "projection" is you need to either inclusively specify "everything" or just exclude what you don't want. So if you want "all fields" then you must ask for "all fields".

Comment: I misunderstood the question.. thanks for the link.. I thought this was not possible..

Comment: db.collection.find({"Rid" : "564b313b3f32df05fc905570"},{"Pid": {$elemMatch:{"Pid":"5630baac3f32df134c18b682"}},"Registration":{$elemMatch:{"Registration": "TN 45 AS 5655"}}},{"_id": false}).pretty()

You were using Registration within pid's elemMatch wihch might not have been giving you the desired result.

Comment: @AnirudhModi am getting only this in the output `{ "_id" : ObjectId("564b313b3f32df05fc905570") }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query nearly gives what you are after, however, it doesn't store `Pid` and `Registration` in an array. If needed, you can create this array with a `$group` statement in combination with a `$push`, however, you will have to include all fields in the group statement.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$match:{"Rid" : "564b313b3f32df05fc905570"}},
{$unwind:"$Pid"},
{$unwind:"$Registration"},
{$match:{"Pid" : "5630baac3f32df134c18b682"}},
{$match:{"Registration" : "TN 45 AS 5655"}}])
```

You can filter the data using `$project`:

```
db.data.aggregate([{$match:{"Rid" : "564b313b3f32df05fc905570"}},
{$unwind:"$Pid"},
{$unwind:"$Registration"},
{$match:{"Pid" : "5630baac3f32df134c18b682"}},
{$match:{"Registration" : "TN 45 AS 5655"}},
{$project:{"_id":0,"Rid":1,"Pid":1,"Registration":1}}])
```

If this query is returning duplicates, as explained in your comment, you can add another `$group` statement to remove the duplicates:

```
db.data.aggregate([{$match:{"Pid" : "5630baac3f32df134c18b682"}},
{$unwind:"$Pid"},
{$unwind:"$Registration"},
{$match:{"Pid" : "5630baac3f32df134c18b682"}},
{$match:{"Registration" : "TN 45 AS 5655"}},
{$project:{"_id":0,"Rid":1,"Pid":1,"Registration":1}},
{$group:{"_id":{"Rid":"$Rid","Pid":"$Pid","Registration":"$Registration"}}},
{$project:    {"_id":0,"Rid":"$_id.Rid","Pid":"$_id.Pid","Registration":"$_id.Registration"}},
```

])

Comment: can I exclude some values from displaying like `_id`. because `_id` gives a json object not serialized error. Usually I use `{"_id": False}` from my code. Is it possible here because am getting an error when using projection

Comment: You can filter the values using `$project`. I have included an example `$project` in my answer.

Comment: I am using your code in `for` loop where the `Registration` value changes but in the output the values are getting repeated do you know why?

I am using `Pid` to match both times instead of `Rid`

Comment: The `Pid` is constant only `Registration` value changes

Comment: Are you getting duplicates ?

Comment: Yes there are duplicate values

Comment: I have extended my answer to remove duplicate records